# Edge detection for color images CannyAlgorithm

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, contour

This is how I managed to use a Sobel Kernel on a GRAYSCALE image.However,I dont actually get how to modify it for a color image.

```
void Soble()
 {
Mat img;
int w = 3;
int k = w / 2;

char fname[MAX_PATH];
openFileDlg(fname);
img = imread(fname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
gaussianFiltering(img);
Mat destinationImg = img.clone();
float sobelY[3][3] = { 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1 };
float sobelX[3][3] = { -1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1 };  
for (int i = k; i < img.rows - k; i++)
{
    for (int j = k; j < img.cols - k; j++)
    {
        float Gx = 0, Gy = 0;

        for (int l = 0; l < w; l++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < w; p++)
            {
                Gx += img.at<uchar>(i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelX[l][p];
                Gy += img.at<uchar>(i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelY[l][p];
            }
        }
        destinationImg.at<uchar>(i, j) = sqrt(Gx*Gx + Gy * Gy) / (4 * sqrt(2));

    }
}
imshow("Intermediar",destinationImg);
imshow("Initial", img);
waitKey(0);

  }
```

I thought of using each RGB chanel but it does not work and even give some errors.

```
        float GxR = 0, GyR = 0;
        float GxG = 0, GyG = 0;
        float GxB = 0, GyB = 0;

        for (int l = 0; l < w; l++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < w; p++)
            {
                GxR += img.at<Vec3b>[0](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelX[l][p];
                GxG += img.at<Vec3b>[1](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelX[l][p];
                GxB += img.at<Vec3b>[2](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelX[l][p];
                GyR += img.at<Vec3b>[0](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelY[l][p];
                GyG += img.at<Vec3b>[1](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelY[l][p];
                GyB += img.at<Vec3b>[2](i + l - k, j + p - k)*sobelY[l][p];
            }
        }
        destinationImg.at<Vec3b>[0](i, j) = sqrt(GxR*GxR + GyR * GyR) / (4 * sqrt(2));
        destinationImg.at<Vec3b>[1](i, j) = sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyB * GyB) / (4 * sqrt(2));
        destinationImg.at<Vec3b>[2](i, j) = sqrt(GxG*GxG + GyG * GyG) / (4 * sqrt(2));
```

Can you please explain how can this code must be rewritten?

Comment: what is "some errors"? that's like going to a doctor and just saying you don't feel well.

Comment: ErrorC3867 'cv::Mat::at': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: ErrorC2109 subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: Here is a tutorial on OpenGL that is focused on Frame Buffers https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers: within this tutorial there is a `kernel` effect that is done in the `shaders` have a look at this as it may help you out. It is towards the end of the tutorial. One of the `kernels` is about `Edge Detection`. Have a read through it.

Comment: For the sake of anyone looking at your code in the future (and this may include you) please don't implement a Sobel operator in a function called `Soble`.

Comment: @TufisiRadu Please feel free to read up on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the image data the wrong way.

```
destinationImg.at<Vec3b>[0](i, j)
```

destinationImg is a Mat of type Vec3b. That means it's a 2d array of three dimensional vectors.

You'r [ ] operator is in the wrong place...

The subscript error message tells you that you're using that operator on something that is neither a pointer nor an array which is not possible.
You get the other error message because you have that operator where the (i,j) is expected.

First you have to get one of these vectors, then you can get its elements.

`destinationImg.at<Vec3b>(i,j)` will give you the vector at i,j.

`destinationImg.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]` will give you the first element of that vector.

Example from the OpenCV documentation:

```
Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
uchar green = intensity.val[1];
uchar red = intensity.val[2];
```

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html